# Remove duplicated rows using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame like this -

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(x=sample(0:1,10,replace=T),y=sample(0:1,10,replace=T),z=1:10)
> df
   x y  z
1  0 1  1
2  1 0  2
3  0 1  3
4  1 1  4
5  1 0  5
6  0 1  6
7  1 0  7
8  1 0  8
9  1 0  9
10 0 1 10
```

I would like to remove duplicate rows based on first two columns. Expected output -

```
df[!duplicated(df[,1:2]),]
  x y z
1 0 1 1
2 1 0 2
4 1 1 4
```

I am specifically looking for a solution using `dplyr` package.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

*Note*: `dplyr` now contains the `distinct` function for this purpose.

Original answer below:

---

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  x = sample(0:1, 10, replace = T),
  y = sample(0:1, 10, replace = T),
  z = 1:10
)
```

One approach would be to group, and then only keep the first row:

```
df %>% group_by(x, y) %>% filter(row_number(z) == 1)

## Source: local data frame [3 x 3]
## Groups: x, y
## 
##   x y z
## 1 0 1 1
## 2 1 0 2
## 3 1 1 4
```

(In dplyr 0.2 you won't need the dummy `z` variable and will just be
able to write `row_number() == 1`)

I've also been thinking about adding a `slice()` function that would
work like:

```
df %>% group_by(x, y) %>% slice(from = 1, to = 1)
```

Or maybe a variation of `unique()` that would let you select which
variables to use:

```
df %>% unique(x, y)
```

Comment: @dotcomken Until then could also just use
`df %>% group_by(x, y) %>% do(head(.,1))`

Comment: @MahbubulMajumder that will work, but is quite slow. dplyr 0.3 will have `distinct()`

Comment: @hadley I like the unique() and distinct() function, however, they all remove the 2nd duplicate from the data frame. what if I want to have all 1st encounters of the duplicate value removed? How could this be done? Thanks for any help!

Comment: @MvZB - wouldn't you just arrange(desc()) and then use distinct?

Comment: I'm sure there is a simple solution but what if I want to get rid of both duplicate rows? I often work with metadata associated with biological samples and if I have duplicate sample IDs, I often can't be sure sure which row has the correct data. Safest bet is to dump both to avoid erroneous metadata associations. Any easy solution besides making a list of duplicate sample IDs and filtering out rows with those IDs?

Comment: Update in 2022: there is also a slice_head(., n =1) function nowadays.

Answer (score 278):

Here is a solution using `dplyr >= 0.5`.

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
  x = sample(0:1, 10, replace = T),
  y = sample(0:1, 10, replace = T),
  z = 1:10
)

> df %>% distinct(x, y, .keep_all = TRUE)
    x y z
  1 0 1 1
  2 1 0 2
  3 1 1 4
```

Comment: This solution appears to be much faster (10 times in my case) than the one provided by Hadley.

Comment: Technically this too is a solution provided by Hadley :-)

Comment: You solve the issue about which rows to remove by arranging, it keeps the first rows.

Answer (score 30):

For completeness’ sake, the following also works:

```
df %>% group_by(x) %>% filter (! duplicated(y))
```

However, I prefer the solution using `distinct`, and I suspect it’s faster, too.

Answer (score 14):

Most of the time, the best solution is using `distinct()` from dplyr, as has already been suggested.

However, here's another approach that uses the `slice()` function from dplyr.

```
# Generate fake data for the example
  library(dplyr)
  set.seed(123)
  df <- data.frame(
    x = sample(0:1, 10, replace = T),
    y = sample(0:1, 10, replace = T),
    z = 1:10
  )

# In each group of rows formed by combinations of x and y
# retain only the first row

    df %>%
      group_by(x, y) %>%
      slice(1)
```

#### Difference from using the `distinct()` function

The advantage of this solution is that it makes it explicit which rows are retained from the original dataframe, and it can pair nicely with the `arrange()` function.

Let's say you had customer sales data and you wanted to retain one record per customer, and you want that record to be the one from their latest purchase. Then you could write:

```
customer_purchase_data %>%
   arrange(desc(Purchase_Date)) %>%
   group_by(Customer_ID) %>%
   slice(1)
```

Answer (score 3):

When selecting columns in R for a reduced data-set you can often end up with duplicates.

These two lines give the same result. Each outputs a unique data-set with two selected columns only:

```
distinct(mtcars, cyl, hp);

summarise(group_by(mtcars, cyl, hp));
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the rows that are duplicated you can use `find_duplicates` from `hablar`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(hablar)

df <- tibble(a = c(1, 2, 2, 4),
             b = c(5, 2, 2, 8))

df %>% find_duplicates()
```