# R duplicate ID variables with different values

Tags: r, duplication

I have a data frame that looks like this;

```
head(x)
user_id    location
1          New York
1          Chicago
2          Atlanta
3          San Antonio
```

I would like to remove the duplicate rows (ie. user_id 1) without regard to their location. So I need a new data frame that only has unique ID's but still has ONE of their locations ( so for ID 1, it doesn't matter if it gets Chicago or New York).

Comment: `x[!duplicated(x$user_id), ]`...

Comment: Can you provide a better code, this code seems already what you are looking for because it has a duplicate row but they belong to different location. Or maybe I miss something, if the case ignore my comment.

Comment: And you could use `distinct()` from the dplyr package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959635/remove-duplicated-rows-using-dplyr/26302351

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try

```
x[!duplicated(x$user_id), ]
  user_id    location
1       1    New_York
3       2     Atlanta
4       3 San_Antonio
```