# Remove semi duplicate rows in R

Tags: r

I have the following data.frame.

```
a <- c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3), rep("C",2), "D")
b <- c(NA,1,2,4,1,NA,2,NA,NA)
c <- c(1,1,2,4,1,1,2,2,2)
d <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
df <-data.frame(a,b,c,d)


  a  b c d
1 A NA 1 1
2 A  1 1 2
3 A  2 2 3
4 B  4 4 4
5 B  1 1 5
6 B NA 1 6
7 C  2 2 7
8 C NA 2 8
9 D NA 2 9
```

I want to remove duplicate rows (based on column A & C) so that the row with values in column B are kept. In this example, rows 1, 6, and 8 are removed.

Comment: Not quite. That removes rows 5 & 6 and removes row 2 instead of 1.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to `order` by 'a', 'b' and the the logical vector based on 'b' so that all 'NA' elements will be last for each group of 'a', and 'b'.  Then, apply the `duplicated` and keep only the non-duplicate elements

```
df1 <- df[order(df$a, df$b, is.na(df$b)),]
df2 <- df1[!duplicated(df1[c('a', 'c')]),]
df2
#  a  b c d
#2 A  1 1 2
#3 A  2 2 3
#5 B  1 1 5
#4 B  4 4 4
#7 C  2 2 7
#9 D NA 2 9

setdiff(seq_len(nrow(df)), row.names(df2) )
#[1] 1 6 8
```

Comment: This works. What's the purpose of `is.na(df$b)` in the order function? I tried it after removing it and df2 is identical.

Comment: @Stephen I just updated the post with the description.  It is to make sure the NA elements are last for each 'a', 'b' pair

Answer (score 1):

First create two datasets, one with duplicates in column a and one without duplicate in column a using the below function :

```
x = df[df$a %in% names(which(table(df$a) > 1)), ]
x1 = df[df$a %in% names(which(table(df$a) ==1)), ]
```

Now use na.omit function on data set x to delete the rows with NA and then rbind x and x1 to the final data set.

```
rbind(na.omit(x),x1)
```

Answer:

```
   a  b c d

2  A  1 1 2

3  A  2 2 3

4  B  4 4 4

5  B  1 1 5

7  C  2 2 7

9  D NA 2 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr` to do this.

```
df %>% distinct(a, c,  .keep_all = TRUE)
```

## Output

```
  a  b c d
1 A NA 1 1
2 A  2 2 3
3 B  4 4 4
4 B  1 1 5
5 C  2 2 7
6 D NA 2 9
```

There are other options in `dplyr`, check this question for details: [Remove duplicated rows using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959635/remove-duplicated-rows-using-dplyr)