# How to Transform Data to Find Index with Same Value

Tags: r, data-manipulation, data-cleaning, data-processing

I intend to find customers who have bought exactly the same products, [image: This is the output that I prefer. I have also provided the dput code below.]

The data I have is customers' behaviors--what they have bought. 
[image: This will be my input (only two columns)]

The example that I provided is a simplified version of my data. Customers will usually buy 10 to 20 products. There are around 50 products that consumers could choose to buy.

I am really confused what is an easy way to transform my data into the output that I prefer. 
Could you please give me any advice? Thanks

**Input:**

```
structure(list(Customer_ID = 1:6, Products = c("Apple, Beer, Diaper", 
"Beer, Apple", "Beer, Apple, Diaper, Diaper", "Apple, Diaper", 
"Diaper, Apple", "Apple, Diaper, Beer, Beer")), .Names = c("Customer_ID", 
"Products"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(Customer_ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Products = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("Customer_ID", "Products")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

**Output**:

```
structure(list(`Products Bought` = c("Apple, Beer, Diaper", "Apple, Diaper"
), Customer_ID = c("1, 3, 6", "4, 5")), .Names = c("Products Bought", 
"Customer_ID"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(`Products Bought` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), Customer_ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("Products Bought", "Customer_ID")), 
    default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```

Comment: Please show a small reproducible using `dput` and the expected output based on that instead of images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am suspicious that you may want to look at structuring your data in a way that is more usable.  In any case, the `tidyverse` can be a helpful way of thinking through your task.

As mentioned, posting code for others to start with can save them time and get you an answer faster.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

d <- data_frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
     , bought=c('Apple, Beer, Diaper','Apple, Beer', 'Apple, Beer, Diaper, Diaper'
               , 'Apple, Diaper', 'Diaper, Apple', 'Apple, Diaper, Beer, Beer'))

d %>% 
## Unnest the values & take care of white space
## - This is the better data structure to have, anyways
mutate(buy=str_split(bought,',')) %>% 
unnest(buy) %>% mutate(buy=str_trim(buy)) %>% select(-bought) %>%

## Get distinct (and sort?)
distinct(id, buy) %>% arrange(id, buy) %>%

## Aggregate by id
group_by(id) %>% summarize(bought=paste(buy,collapse=', ')) %>% ungroup %>%

## Count
group_by(bought) %>% summarize(ids=paste(id,collapse=',')) %>% ungroup
```

EDIT: referencing [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26302351/6570011) for getting distinct combinations faster / cleaner in dplyr

Answer (score 0):

Using the given `input` data and `data.table`, this can be written as (rather convoluted) "one-liner":

```
dcast(unique(setDT(input)[, strsplit(Products, ", "), Customer_ID])[
  order(Customer_ID, V1)], 
  Customer_ID ~ ., paste, collapse = ", ")[
    , .(Customers = paste(Customer_ID, collapse = ", ")), .(Products = .)]
#              Products Customers
#1: Apple, Beer, Diaper   1, 3, 6
#2:         Apple, Beer         2
#3:       Apple, Diaper      4, 5
```

Note that the OP has dropped the second line with only one customer from 
 the expected output but hasn't mentioned any criteria for filtering the output in the question.

#### Input data

(As given by OP):

```
input <- structure(list(Customer_ID = 1:6, Products = c("Apple, Beer, Diaper", 
"Beer, Apple", "Beer, Apple, Diaper, Diaper", "Apple, Diaper", 
"Diaper, Apple", "Apple, Diaper, Beer, Beer")), .Names = c("Customer_ID", 
"Products"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), spec = structure(list(cols = structure(list(Customer_ID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_integer", 
"collector")), Products = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("Customer_ID", "Products")), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector"))), .Names = c("cols", "default"), class = "col_spec"))
```