# Randomly remove duplicated rows using dplyr()

Tags: r, dplyr

As a follow-up question to this one: [Remove duplicated rows using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959635/remove-duplicated-rows-using-dplyr), I have the following:

*How do you randomly remove duplicated rows using dplyr() (among others)?*

My command now is:

```
data.uniques <- distinct(data, KEYVARIABLE, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

But it returns the first occurrence of the KEYVARIABLE. I want that behaviour to be random: so anywhere between `1` and `n` occurrences of that KEYVARIABLE.

For instance:

```
KEYVARIABLE BMI
1 24.2
2 25.3
2 23.2
3 18.9
4 19
4 20.1
5 23.0
```

Currently my command returns:

```
KEYVARIABLE BMI
1 24.2
2 25.3
3 18.9
4 19
5 23.0
```

I want it to randomly return one of the `n` duplicated rows, for instance:

```
KEYVARIABLE BMI
1 24.2
2 23.2
3 18.9
4 19
5 23.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One option would be to group by 'KEYVARIABLE' and then `sample` the sequence of rows to select the row and Subset the dataset

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .SD[sample(.N)[1]], KEYVARIABLE]
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(KEYVARIABLE) %>%
   sample_n(1)
```

Comment: Consider big `.N`: `microbenchmark::microbenchmark(sample(1000, 1), sample(1000)[1])`

Answer (score 6):

Just shuffle rows before selecting first occurrence (using `distinct`).

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df[sample(1:nrow(df)), ], 
         KEYVARIABLE, 
         .keep_all = TRUE)
```

Comment: Also `df1 %>% slice(sample(n())) %>% distinct(KEYVARIABLE, .keep_all = TRUE)` for those hooked on chains.

Answer (score 1):

By using `dplyr`

```
df%>%dplyr::mutate(A=sample(1:dim(df)[1]))%>%group_by(KEYVARIABLE)%>%dplyr::slice(which.min(A))
```