# How to completely remove duplicate rows from data?

Tags: r

I will borrow an example for this question of the same name: [Remove duplicated rows using dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22959635/remove-duplicated-rows-using-dplyr)

```
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(x=sample(0:1,10,replace=T),y=sample(0:1,10,replace=T),z=1:10)

> df
   x y  z
1  0 1  1
2  1 0  2
3  0 1  3
4  1 1  4
5  1 0  5
6  0 1  6
7  1 0  7
8  1 0  8
9  1 0  9
10 0 1 10

df[!duplicated(df[,1:2]),]
  x y z
1 0 1 1
2 1 0 2
4 1 1 4
```

The problem with the example is that it keeps one row and removes other duplicate rows. I need to completely remove all duplicate rows.

The final result should only have one row that is unique:

```
  x y z
4 1 1 4
```

Already answered here: [How can I remove all duplicates so that NONE are left in a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763216/how-can-i-remove-all-duplicates-so-that-none-are-left-in-a-data-frame)

Thank you Jaap. I promise I searched, a lot, and all results I found were like the example I posted.

Comment: the original turns out was a different question about data sets, just poorly named. However I still did not know the remove duplicates answer so this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `duplicated` with `fromLast` as well.  The `duplicated` alone will give TRUE for rows that are duplicated from the second elements i.e. if the values are `1, 2, 1, 2 3`, `duplicated` gives `FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE`.  In order to get both first and second as TRUE, we need to apply it in reverse (`fromLast = TRUE`) and then wrap with `|` gives either one of them

```
df[!(duplicated(df[,1:2])|duplicated(df[1:2], fromLast = TRUE)),]
#  x y z
#4 1 1 4
```

---

Or another option would be

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(x, y) %>%
     filter(n() == 1)
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), 
    y = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), z = 1:10), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```

Comment: that works, but I don't understand how. can you point me to a tutorial on this syntax? the | specifically? thanks.

Comment: nevermind the link Jaap posted explains it and | is just an or as expected.